# How can I access Laravel Response Object from within controller?

Tags: laravel, header, response

I have middleware where I am assigning http headers to the request/response.

```
$response = $next($request)->header('x-robots-tag', 'noindex', false);
```

In the middleware, I can also apply this line after executing the above, to get the value I had just set...

```
echo $response->headers->get('x-robots-tag');
```

But, I want to access this outside of middleware but I'm not sure how to get the Response object back to achieve this.

How can I get the $response object from within my controller?

```
$response = \WHAT\GOES\HERE?;
echo $response->headers->get('x-robots-tag');
```

I can't seem to figure out what to put in the ***\WHAT\GOES\HERE*** part to access the response object again.

### Update #1:

---

Still unresolved, but part of the problem appears to be that in order to add the header tags to the Response object within middleware requires `$next($request)` and the $next Closure causes the response processing to be done after the controller code has executed.  So even though I'm not sure how to target the Response object from within the controller, it doesn't look like it would have the header tag assigned until afterward anyway.

I could set the headers directly in PHP in the middleware with

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next /*, $tags */)
{
    $tags = array_except(func_get_args(), [0,1]);
    if( count($tags) > 0){
        header('x-robots-tag: ' . implode(', ', $tags));
    }
    return  $next($request);
}
```

and then access it in the controller by pulling it out of the `headers_list()` but that's not ideal and working outside of the laravel ways...

For context, the idea was to assign middleware to routes and with the middleware assign the `x-robots-tag` response header with the desired attributes. `noindex, nofollow`, whatever... Then I was hoping to capture this and populate the equivalent meta tags accordingly using the data provided to the `x-robots-tag`.  A two-birds with one stone sort of approach, but it has proven more difficult than I had expected.

Comment: [Laravel 5.8 documentation on Responses.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses)

Comment: Thanks. I have read through that documentation page multiple times and have yet to find an answer there. :(